# Sympy on PyPy - Sometimes 6x faster, sometimes 4x slower

Tags: python, performance, sympy, pypy

Here, pypy is slower in calculating, whether a given number is prime:

```
C:\Users\User>python -m timeit -n10 -s"from sympy import isprime" "isprime(2**521-1)"
10 loops, best of 3: 25.9 msec per loop

C:\Users\User>pypy -m timeit -n10 -s"from sympy import isprime" "isprime(2**521-1)"
10 loops, best of 3: 97.9 msec per loop
```

Here, pypy is faster in creating a list of primes (from 1 to 1000000):

```
C:\Users\User>pypy -m timeit -n10 -s"from sympy import sieve" "primes = list(sieve.primerange(1, 10**6))"
10 loops, best of 3: 2.12 msec per loop

C:\Users\User>python -m timeit -n10 -s"from sympy import sieve" "primes = list(sieve.primerange(1, 10**6))"
10 loops, best of 3: 11.9 msec per loop
```

Very surprising, hard to understand.

> “If you want your code to run faster, you should probably just use PyPy.” — Guido van Rossum (creator of Python)

Am I missing something?

Comment: PyPy's advantages are not going to be apparent for very short examples that just do one computation.  See the bottom of [this page](http://pypy.org/performance.html).

Comment: Did you try several times your initial computation? I tried several times and I always got a (slightly) better time with `pypy`! (Tried with Linux Mint if it matters)

Comment: I tried it several times, always with the same results. Here's one more:

Comment: `C:\Users\User>python -m timeit -n10 -s"from sympy import isprime" "isprime(2**521-1);isprime(2**1279-1)"
10 loops, best of 3: 287 msec per loop`

`C:\Users\User>pypy -m timeit -n10 -s"from sympy import isprime" "isprime(2**521-1);isprime(2**1279-1)"
10 loops, best of 3: 1.3 sec per loop`

Comment: @BrenBarn: That doesn't explain, why pypy is much faster in one case, and much slower in a different case.

Comment: @lifolofi: I think it suggests something, because your second example is comuting many primes whereas the first is computing only one.  Saying "PyPy is faster" doesn't mean it will be faster in every single case.

Comment: It looks like a windows-only problem. I just compared sympy.isprime and sympy.sieve.primerange on Linux. There, pypy takes 2/3 of the time for isprime and only 10% for primerange, compared to python.

Comment: More generally, SymPy is often slower on PyPy, especially when using expressions, because it doesn't handle it doesn't handle the dynamicism that SymPy uses so well. In this case, though, it looks like the answer is likely related to gmpy, as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 5):

`isprime` has a fast path for when `gmpy` is installed. `gmpy` has bindings to a highly optimized C library, and is probably only installed on CPython.

Comment: "gmpy and gmpy2 rely on too many internal details of CPython to be ported to PyPy." This is a statement from the gmpy maintainer on Stackoverflow.

Comment: You are right: `C:\Windows\system32>python -m timeit -n10 -s"from gmpy2 import is_prime" "is_prime(2**521-1);is_prime(2**1279-1)"
10 loops, best of 3: 29.8 msec per loop`